# Returning a variable in while loop

Tags: python-3.x

I am encountering a problem for an assignment in my python3 class.

The code runs how is supposed to.
Ask the user the names of their dogs until they type 'DONE' and then tell them that each of their dogs are awesome by name.

However when I run the program you have to go through the input twice before you can get an output. I am new to this so I am sure the fix is quite simple.
Here is what I have:

```
def main():
    doggo_names = get_doggo_names()
    output_names(doggo_names)

def get_doggo_names():
    name = ''
    names = []
    while name != 'DONE':
        name = input('Name of doggo: ')
        if name != 'DONE':
            names.append(name)
    
    return names

def output_names(doggo_names):

    print()

    for names in get_doggo_names():
        print(names + ' ', end='is awesome.\n')

main()
```

Comment: You are passing the list of dog name to `output_name()` you don't need to call `get_doggo_names()` again in the for loop. Just `for names in doggo_names`

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953) Step through your code. It will become pretty clear why it asks for user input two times

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your code should be like this:

```
def main():
    doggo_names = get_doggo_names()
    output_names(doggo_names)

def get_doggo_names():
    name = ''
    names = []
    while name != 'DONE':
        name = input('Name of doggo: ')
        if name != 'DONE':
            names.append(name)

    return names

def output_names(names):

    for name in names:
        print(name + ' ', end='is awesome.\n')

main()
```

Comment: Thank! I''ll let my professor know that his starter code should be changed.

Comment: @ZachBanks Lol, no! `get_doggo_names` returns a list. `output_names` takes an argument and outputs those names. The professor's starter code presumably didn't include the contents of `output_names`. _You_ made the error here -- calling `get_doggo_names` _another time_ in `output_names` instead of using the `doggo_names` that was passed to it.

Comment: Yes you are right @PranavHosangadi. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Please explain what changes you made and why. An answer that includes only a dump of the fixed code isn't as helpful because it doesn't explain why those changes were needed. See [answer]